# Bootstrap Row Cutting off Bottom of Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns right now on the same row with one column being a table that can have "tr's" added to it dynamically.  So when this table is nearly empty, it is very small height-wise.  My other column is a fixed height (half the page) so it is taller than my table column when the table is nearly empty.  When the table is in the near-empty state however, it cuts off the bottom of my other column to keep the heights of both of them equal.  Here's a picture of what it looks like in that state:

[image: Cutoff]

And here's my code for the row minus the insides of each column (I'm also using Bootstrap's offcanvas plugin):

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right"> 
    <div class="components col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-hover sortable" id="table">
    <div class="sidebar-offcanvas preview" id="sidebar">
```

Also, if you're wondering, the Preview column I have on there is off the page until a button is clicked.  When it does come on, the Components column is compressed into a col-lg-8.  Sorry if this is confusing!  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: An example on jsFiddle would be really helpful to diagnose this issue but I'm pretty sure this is caused by a container around both columns that is cutting it off because floated elements don't expand their parent containers.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley so what is the fix?